# Phonegap build: How to explicitly ask for permissions?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, phonegap-build

I am building a hybrid app for Android and iOS, and using phonegap build cli-5.2.0

I am using a camera plugin

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="2.2.0" />
```

I have this line specified in my config.xml

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
```

And I notice that on my android device, it only asks for
read/write access of USB storage. When using the camera to take a photo, android doesn't ask for any permission and the camera just some how works.

I want to know how to explicitly require Camera permission on android prior to app installation? I need to have it because I believe it is causing some other bug related to a video functionality my app has.

I have tried to build without the permission none line, but that did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to add a config-file element. I don't know why it is so hard to find.

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="add">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</gap:config-file>
```

Comment: do you add this to config.xml?

Comment: @Pete Yep thats where you put them. This was 2 years ago tho, i am not sure if the current phonegap still works this way. Also this was for phone gap build cli-5.2.0